# Why footer on the 2nd page is not at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that displays header and footer on every printed page. So far, the header and footer's position already correct when there is only 1 page to be printed. But when there is 2 pages, that is when this problem occurs. The footer on the 2nd page will not be positioned at the very bottom of the page. I have already set the position fixed and bottom to 0 but still it is still happening. Can someone point out why is this happening and how can i fix it?

```
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="divOverflow">
                        <table class=layout style="height:100%; width: 100%; background-color:#ffffff;">
                            <thead style="<%=_sStylingHeader%>">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='vertical-align: top'>
                                        <%=_sLetterHeader %>
                                        <hr style='border-bottom:1px solid black' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody style="<%=_sStylingContent%>">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top">
                                        <div><br /><%=_sLetterContent %><br /></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot style="<%=_sStylingFooter%>">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='vertical-align: bottom'>
                                        <hr style='border-bottom:1px solid black' />
                                        <%=_sLetterFooter %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


 _sStylingHeader = "height: 10%; width: 100%; visibility: visible; position: fixed; top: 0";
 _sStylingContent = "height: 82%; width: 100%; visibility: visible";
 _sStylingFooter = "height: 8%; width: 100%; visibility: visible; position: fixed; bottom: 0";
```

[image: Proper footer]

[image: Footer is not all the way to the bottom]

Comment: In your code it seems you've mixed your styles up..  Your tfoot is using _sStylingContent

Comment: @HenrikClausen hi Henrik. Thank you for the reply and sorry for the messed up. But i have already change it to the correct styling but the issue is not yet fixed. Do u have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`heigh:100%` is a little bit tricky. because it will only take the full height of its parent. but if the parent has not height declared, then it will not do anything.

so what I suggest is you add some JavaScript code that gets the height of the screen and add it to the parent element.

example:

```
<body>
<table height="100%">
</table>
<script>
window.onload = function get_body() {
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.height = h; 
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Couldnt he just set height to 100 vh instead of using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes that's possible too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your content on a structure similar to:

```
<div id="page-container">
   <div id="content-wrap">
     <!-- all other page content -->
   </div>
   <footer id="footer"></footer>
 </div>
```

Your css should be something like:

```
#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}
```

**What does this do:**

The page-container goes around everything on the page, and sets its minimum height to 100% of the viewport height (vh). As it is relative, its child elements can be set with absolute position based on it later.

The content-wrap has a bottom padding that is the height of the footer, ensuring that exactly enough space is left for the footer inside the container they are both in. A wrapping div is used here that would contain all other page content.

The footer is set to absolute, sticking to the bottom: 0 of the page-container it is within. This is important, as it is not absolute to the viewport, but will move down if the page-container is taller than the viewport. As stated, its height, arbitrarily set to 2.5rem here, is used in the content-wrap above it.

Comment: i've tried this one and many more but it still doesn't work. Maybe something in the solution that overrides the css. do you have any idea what else is the root cause?